# Storing Client Certs and private keys in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, client-certificates, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-kms

I am working on a microservice which needs to talk to customer servers via REST. This is a mutual TLS connection. Our requirement is that client cert and private is given by customer itself, this means we have separate client cert and private key for each customer. What is the best way to store them in AWS and load them into microservices on startup? Secret manager with KMS or S3 with KMS? Does storing certs and keys in S3 raise any compliance concerns?

We will have to manage rotation manually as it depends on when customer changes the cert and key.